# Show that exactly one of the equations has a solution.

Tags: optimization

Show that exactly one of:
\begin{cases} B^Tv = 0\\ d^Tv = 1  \end{cases}
or
$$Bu=d$$
has a solution.
I tried with Farkas lemma, but I run into trouble.

Comment: The title and body contain two different questions. Do you want to show that only one equation has a solution, or exactly one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = u_1 - u_2$ such that $u_1, u_2 \geq 0$. Then the second equation is equivalent to

$$B \cdot (u_1-u_2) = d, u_1, u_2 \geq 0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \begin{pmatrix} B & -B \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{pmatrix} =  d, u_1,u_2 \geq 0$$

Moreover the first equation is equivalent to

$$B^T \cdot v \leq 0, B^T \cdot v \geq 0, d^T \cdot v<0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} B^T \\ -B^T \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} v \\ v \end{pmatrix} \geq 0, d^T \cdot v <0$$

Now you can apply [Farkas' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma).

Comment: Seems good but i dont see how $$d^Tv<0$$ in the last equation.. (I see it know) thanks!

Comment: If there exist $v$ such that $B^T v =0$, $d^T \cdot v=1$, then $w:=-v$ solves $B^T w =0$, $d^T w<0$. On the other hand: If there exists a $w$ such that $B^T w = 0$, $d^T w<0$, then $v:= w/(d^T \cdot w) solves $B^T \cdot v=0$, $d^T \cdot v = 1$. Thus, buth formulations are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little optimization theory, but if we perform [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) to get $B=U\Sigma V^T$ and absorb the orthogonal matrices $U,V$ into $u,v,d$, the two systems can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
&\begin{cases} \Sigma^T \tilde{v} = 0,\\ \tilde{d}^T \tilde{v} = 1,\end{cases}\\
&\Sigma \tilde{u}=\tilde{d}.
\end{align}
where $\tilde{v}=U^Tv,\ \tilde{d}=U^Td$ and $\tilde{u}=V^Tu$. As $\Sigma$ is a (rectangular) diagonal matrix, the conclusion should be clear.

Comment: Yes but that does just show that they dont have a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which does not involve Farkas lemma.

1. First observe that it is not possible to have solutions $u$ and $v$ to both equations at the same time.
   If there were such a solutions, then
   $$0=u^T 0 = u^T B^T v=(Bu)^T v=d^T v=1,$$
   hence a contradiction.
2. Then if the equation $Bu=d$ has no solution we can prove that the other system of equations has a solution. Indeed in this case $d$ is not contained in the span $span(B)$ of the columns of $B$ and thus
   $$d=d_1+d_2,\quad \text{with }d_1\in  span(B),\, d_2\in span(B)^\perp,\, d_2\neq 0\,.$$
   The vector $v=d_2/\|d_2\|^2$ is a solution of the first set of equations because
   $$d^Tv=\frac{d_1^Td_2 +d_2^Td_2}{\|d_2\|^2}=\frac{0+\|d_2\|^2}{\|d_2\|^2}=1$$
   and
   $$B^T v=\frac{1}{\|d_2\|^2} B^T d_2=0$$
   since $d_2\in span(B)^\perp$. Thus there is also at least one of the two sets of equations with a solution.